# StartAR method Intel XDK

Tags: android, intel-xdk

I use augmented reality in practice to intel XDK and I need use StartAR() method in a agumented reality app, but, it's not found, still working this method?

Comment: You need to add the plugin.  Go to the build settings, Included plugins.  On the right hand side under "featured and custom cordova plugins" you will see "Display"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `intel.xdk.display` plugin has been deprecated:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/xdkdocs#intel.xdk.display

While it's still available in the current release, at some future point it will probably go away, so you may not want to depend on it going forward.  It recommends using the *meta viewport tag*, but that probably won't help you for `startAR()`.  You might want to ask in the xdk forum what alternative is available, if any:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk

If I find any further info, I'll update here.

Comment: I think this link will work more reliably - the deep-linking on their doc site is a challenge: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/xdkdocs#507858